# Parse Hook Names in React Dev Tools is not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-devtools

[image]

State definitions: [image]

I really need to which state is causing a bug in my code, but the magic wand tool doesnt seem to be working. Please help.

Comment: For me, when I use a custom hook, dev tools magic wand fails to show hook names. You can try without custom hooks